# Javascript: Use regex to check if a string has values only from another one?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching, match

I have a `characters` string which contains the allowed chars. I would like to check another string (`input`) if it has values only from the `characters`.

I don't no if it's possible but looking for a solution which uses `regex` and `match()` to determine if the input has only allowed characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyWTX/2/)

Give this a go. Success will be true when the test string contains only the allowed characters. This is case sensitive.

```
var allowedCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var regex = new RegExp("^[" + allowedCharacters + "]*$");
var testString = "abc#@#";
var success = regex.test(testString);
```

For case in-sensitive replace the respective line with the below. This adds a regex modifier.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[" + allowedCharacters + "]*$", "i");
```

If you have special characters in your allowedCharacters variable you must escape them with a double slash. So to allow the square bracket character as well you must use.

```
var allowedCharacters = "abc\\[";
```

This is because the first backslash is for the string escape and the second is to make it an escape in the regex.

Comment: you need to pay attention to special characters here (e.g. `allowed="ab-x"`)

Comment: I don't know but it doesn't seem to work at me. The allowed chars are `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, however it returns true if the `testString` is `abc#@#`. :( What's wrong with it?

Comment: one more question, do I need to use the double blackslash before all the special characters? eg.: `abc\\!\\?\\@\\(\\)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor to create a regexp from a string:

```
function validStringUnsanitized(allowed, str) {
    var re = new RegExp("^[" + allowed + "]+$");
    return re.test(str);
}

> validStringUnsanitized('abx', 'abx');
true
> validStringUnsanitized('abx', 'ght');
true
```

But if you want to allow special characters, you need to sanitize the allowed one. Otherwise you get unwanted results:

```
// the regex becomes [ab-x] which is from a to x
> validStringUnsanitized('ab-x', 'ghai');
true
> validStringUnsanitized(']ab', 'ab');
false
```

So you have to escape some chars like this:

```
function validString(allowed, str) {
    var sanitized = allowed.replace(/([\]\-\\])/g, '\\$1')
    var re = new RegExp("^[" + sanitized + "]+$");
    return re.test(str);
}

> validString(']ab-x\\[', 'abxaabbx');
true
> validString(']ab-x\\[', 'ab-\\xb[]ab');
true
> validString(']ab-x\\[', 'ghai');
false
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKzJE/)

Answer (score 1):

In case you wish to avoid using regex, you could consider something like:

```
var valid_chars = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'],
    ret;

//or valid_chars = string.split('');

ret = isValid('test', valid_chars);   //false
ret = isValid('aeyaa', valid_chars);  //true
ret = isValid('aeyaab', valid_chars); //false

function isValid(input, check)
{
    if (typeof input === 'string')
        input = input.split('');

    if (typeof check === 'string')
        check = input.split('');

    if (typeof input !== 'object')
    {
        console.log('isValid() failed: input not array');
        return;
    }

    if (typeof check !== 'object')
    {
        console.log('isValid() failed: check not array');
        return;
    }


    for (var x = 0; x < input.length; ++x)
    {
        var char_isvalid = false;

        for (var y = 0; y < check.length; ++y)
        {
            if (input[x].toLowerCase() === check[y].toLowerCase())
            {
                char_isvalid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (! char_isvalid)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this function

http://jsfiddle.net/SXeTJ/

```
var allowed = 'abcdef';

function CheckAllowedWithRegex(str,allowed){
   var pattern = new RegExp("[^"+allowed+"]");
   return str.match(pattern) == null;
}

var str1 = 'aaabcc';
var str2 = 'aavbllkwqxx';

alert(  CheckAllowedWithRegex(str1,allowed ) ); // output is true

alert(  CheckAllowedWithRegex(str2,allowed ) ); // output is false
```